# Outputting that number along with a single character of the repeating sequence

Tags: java

folks! I've been practicing different tasks on Java and this one has been taking me a while to figure out. A user has to enter only `String` of letters and for example, if a user enters smth like `wwwzddfffff` the ouput should be `3w1z2d5f` or, another example, `kklllk` and the ouput should be `3k3l`. The method `runLength()` takes the occurrence of each repeating character and outputs that number along with a single character of the repeating sequence.
What I am getting is:

```
Enter any String: 
wwwwzzzz
7z




    import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunLength {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any String: ");
        String word = kbd.nextLine();
        String result = runLength(word);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static String runLength(String word)
    {
        char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
        char firstChar = chars[0];
        char temp = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String result = "";

        for(int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++)
        {

            if(firstChar == chars[i])
            {
                temp = firstChar;
                count++;
                result = count+""+temp;
            }

            else if(firstChar != chars[i])
            {
                temp = chars[i];
                count++;
                result = count+""+temp;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class test
{


public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(runlength("aaabbc"));
    }
static String runlength(String s)
{
    String current="";
    int count = 1;
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 1; i < c.length; i++)
    {
        if (c[i]==c[i-1])
            count++;

        else 
        {
            current = current + count + Character.toString(c[i-1]);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return current + count + Character.toString(c[c.length-1]);
}
}
```

Comment: No HashMaps required :3

Comment: Could you please explaing this line:  `return current + count + Character.toString(c[c.length-1]);` , @xrisk ?

Comment: @John see what happens is that in the for-loop you're counting everything but the last letter chain. SO the last letter doesn't get added in the loop.

Comment: the return statement adds that to the string

Comment: @John, by the way how do you want to handle something like aaabbaaa?

Comment: my function will give you 3a2b3a for that

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, one last question: why in `else` statement `count` gets assigned back to `1`, @xrisk ?

Comment: because, the count variable tracks the length of the letter chains - so everytime we fnd a letter that breaks the letter chain (aaabb - at the a,b junction) we set it to 1, which implies that a new chain has beguni

Comment: and sorry for the sloppy indentation - so doesn't like tabs :3

Answer (score 0):

Would like you to rewrite runLength method.

```
public static Map runLength(String word) {
        char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
        char firstChar = chars[0];
        Map charMap = new HashMap();

        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if(charMap.contains(chars[i])
                charMap.put(chars[i],++charMap.get(chars[i]));
            else
               charMap.put(chars[i],1);
        }
        return charMap;
    }
```

// in the main method

```
Map myMap = runLength(word);

for (Entry entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.print(myMap.get(entry.getKey())+entry.getKey());
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without using `Collections` and/or `StringBuilder`?

Comment: If you do not want to use collections, then you need to make a class, which has string and freq as their attributes. Make an array of that class, and keep iterating the array for each char. if exists, increase the frequency else add it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a HashMap will solve your problem. Try:

```
 Map<Character, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    for(char c: chars){
        if(counter.containsKey(c)){
            counter.put(c, c.get(c) ++);
        }
        else{
            counter.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
```

Then to print:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (Character c : counter.keySet()) {
        builder.append(c);
        builder.append(counter.get(c));
}

return builder.toString();
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without using `Collections` and/or `StringBuilder`? @TotZam

Comment: Instead of StringBuilder, you can use +=, but not recommended. `String result = ""; for(Character c: counter.keySet(){ result += (c + "" + counter.get(c));} return result;`

Comment: And you can use 2 parallel arrays instead of a HashMap, but Maps are way more efficient and easier to use, once you know how to use them.

Comment: I started writing code using arrays, yet stopped since it really does not make sense to use anything other than Maps for this problem. Maps let you easily check to see if the character already exists. If you use arrays, you would need to search through the entire array of unique characters each time. My advice is to simply use HashMap.